# Why is my Request empty in PHP/Laravel when using POST

Tags: php, laravel, postman

I relatively new to laravel and am trying to develop an API.
So far I have successfully implemented some GET Routes, but I am struggeling with the POST Routes.
The Problem is, when testing the POST Route with Postman, the Request is empty, eventhough I am sending JSON Data.

I don't think I have misconfigured anything in the Postman Request, but here is my configuration anyways:

[image: Headers]

[image: Body]

[image: Settings]

Response:

```
NULL
array(0) {
}
array(0) {
}
<script>
    Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { var refStyle = doc.createElement('style'), rxEsc = /([.*+?^${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, idRx = /\bsf-dump-\d+-ref[012]\w+\b/, keyHint = 0 <= navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC') ? 'Cmd' : 'Ctrl', addEventListener = function (e, n, cb) { e.addEventListener(n, cb, false); }; (doc.documentElement.firstElementChild || doc.documentElement.children[0]).appendChild(refStyle); if (!doc.addEventListener) { addEventListener = function (element, eventName, callback) { element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, function (e) { e.preventDefault = function () {e.returnValue = false;}; e.target = e.srcElement; callback(e); }); }; } function toggle(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className, arrow, newClass; if (/\bsf-dump-compact\b/.test(oldClass)) { arrow = '&#9660;'; newClass = 'sf-dump-expanded'; } else if (/\bsf-dump-expanded\b/.test(oldClass)) { arrow = '&#9654;'; newClass = 'sf-dump-compact'; } else { return false; } if (doc.createEvent && s.dispatchEvent) { var event = doc.createEvent('Event'); event.initEvent('sf-dump-expanded' === newClass ? 'sfbeforedumpexpand' : 'sfbeforedumpcollapse', true, false); s.dispatchEvent(event); } a.lastChild.innerHTML = arrow; s.className = s.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-(compact|expanded)\b/, newClass); if (recursive) { try { a = s.querySelectorAll('.'+oldClass); for (s = 0; s < a.length; ++s) { if (-1 == a[s].className.indexOf(newClass)) { a[s].className = newClass; a[s].previousSibling.lastChild.innerHTML = arrow; } } } catch (e) { } } return true; }; function collapse(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className; if (/\bsf-dump-expanded\b/.test(oldClass)) { toggle(a, recursive); return true; } return false; }; function expand(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className; if (/\bsf-dump-compact\b/.test(oldClass)) { toggle(a, recursive); return true; } return false; }; function collapseAll(root) { var a = root.querySelector('a.sf-dump-toggle'); if (a) { collapse(a, true); expand(a); return true; } return false; } function reveal(node) { var previous, parents = []; while ((node = node.parentNode || {}) && (previous = node.previousSibling) && 'A' === previous.tagName) { parents.push(previous); } if (0 !== parents.length) { parents.forEach(function (parent) { expand(parent); }); return true; } return false; } function highlight(root, activeNode, nodes) { resetHighlightedNodes(root); Array.from(nodes||[]).forEach(function (node) { if (!/\bsf-dump-highlight\b/.test(node.className)) { node.className = node.className + ' sf-dump-highlight'; } }); if (!/\bsf-dump-highlight-active\b/.test(activeNode.className)) { activeNode.className = activeNode.className + ' sf-dump-highlight-active'; } } function resetHighlightedNodes(root) { Array.from(root.querySelectorAll('.sf-dump-str, .sf-dump-key, .sf-dump-public, .sf-dump-protected, .sf-dump-private')).forEach(function (strNode) { strNode.className = strNode.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-highlight\b/, ''); strNode.className = strNode.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-highlight-active\b/, ''); }); } return function (root, x) { root = doc.getElementById(root); var indentRx = new RegExp('^('+(root.getAttribute('data-indent-pad') || ' ').replace(rxEsc, '\\$1')+')+', 'm'), options = {"maxDepth":1,"maxStringLength":160,"fileLinkFormat":false}, elt = root.getElementsByTagName('A'), len = elt.length, i = 0, s, h, t = []; while (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); for (i in x) { options[i] = x[i]; } function a(e, f) { addEventListener(root, e, function (e, n) { if ('A' == e.target.tagName) { f(e.target, e); } else if ('A' == e.target.parentNode.tagName) { f(e.target.parentNode, e); } else { n = /\bsf-dump-ellipsis\b/.test(e.target.className) ? e.target.parentNode : e.target; if ((n = n.nextElementSibling) && 'A' == n.tagName) { if (!/\bsf-dump-toggle\b/.test(n.className)) { n = n.nextElementSibling || n; } f(n, e, true); } } }); }; function isCtrlKey(e) { return e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey; } function xpathString(str) { var parts = str.match(/[^'"]+|['"]/g).map(function (part) { if ("'" == part) { return '"\'"'; } if ('"' == part) { return "'\"'"; } return "'" + part + "'"; }); return "concat(" + parts.join(",") + ", '')"; } function xpathHasClass(className) { return "contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' " + className +" ')"; } addEventListener(root, 'mouseover', function (e) { if ('' != refStyle.innerHTML) { refStyle.innerHTML = ''; } }); a('mouseover', function (a, e, c) { if (c) { e.target.style.cursor = "pointer"; } else if (a = idRx.exec(a.className)) { try { refStyle.innerHTML = 'pre.sf-dump .'+a[0]+'{background-color: #B729D9; color: #FFF !important; border-radius: 2px}'; } catch (e) { } } }); a('click', function (a, e, c) { if (/\bsf-dump-toggle\b/.test(a.className)) { e.preventDefault(); if (!toggle(a, isCtrlKey(e))) { var r = doc.getElementById(a.getAttribute('href').substr(1)), s = r.previousSibling, f = r.parentNode, t = a.parentNode; t.replaceChild(r, a); f.replaceChild(a, s); t.insertBefore(s, r); f = f.firstChild.nodeValue.match(indentRx); t = t.firstChild.nodeValue.match(indentRx); if (f && t && f[0] !== t[0]) { r.innerHTML = r.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp('^'+f[0].replace(rxEsc, '\\$1'), 'mg'), t[0]); } if (/\bsf-dump-compact\b/.test(r.className)) { toggle(s, isCtrlKey(e)); } } if (c) { } else if (doc.getSelection) { try { doc.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); } catch (e) { doc.getSelection().empty(); } } else { doc.selection.empty(); } } else if (/\bsf-dump-str-toggle\b/.test(a.className)) { e.preventDefault(); e = a.parentNode.parentNode; e.className = e.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-str-(expand|collapse)\b/, a.parentNode.className); } }); elt = root.getElementsByTagName('SAMP'); len = elt.length; i = 0; while (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); len = t.length; for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) { elt = t[i]; if ('SAMP' == elt.tagName) { a = elt.previousSibling || {}; if ('A' != a.tagName) { a = doc.createElement('A'); a.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; elt.parentNode.insertBefore(a, elt); } else { a.innerHTML += ' '; } a.title = (a.title ? a.title+'\n[' : '[')+keyHint+'+click] Expand all children'; a.innerHTML += '<span>&#9660;</span>'; a.className += ' sf-dump-toggle'; x = 1; if ('sf-dump' != elt.parentNode.className) { x += elt.parentNode.getAttribute('data-depth')/1; } elt.setAttribute('data-depth', x); var className = elt.className; elt.className = 'sf-dump-expanded'; if (className ? 'sf-dump-expanded' !== className : (x > options.maxDepth)) { toggle(a); } } else if (/\bsf-dump-ref\b/.test(elt.className) && (a = elt.getAttribute('href'))) { a = a.substr(1); elt.className += ' '+a; if (/[\[{]$/.test(elt.previousSibling.nodeValue)) { a = a != elt.nextSibling.id && doc.getElementById(a); try { s = a.nextSibling; elt.appendChild(a); s.parentNode.insertBefore(a, s); if (/^[@#]/.test(elt.innerHTML)) { elt.innerHTML += ' <span>&#9654;</span>'; } else { elt.innerHTML = '<span>&#9654;</span>'; elt.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; } elt.className += ' sf-dump-toggle'; } catch (e) { if ('&' == elt.innerHTML.charAt(0)) { elt.innerHTML = '&hellip;'; elt.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; } } } } } if (doc.evaluate && Array.from && root.children.length > 1) { root.setAttribute('tabindex', 0); SearchState = function () { this.nodes = []; this.idx = 0; }; SearchState.prototype = { next: function () { if (this.isEmpty()) { return this.current(); } this.idx = this.idx < (this.nodes.length - 1) ? this.idx + 1 : 0; return this.current(); }, previous: function () { if (this.isEmpty()) { return this.current(); } this.idx = this.idx > 0 ? this.idx - 1 : (this.nodes.length - 1); return this.current(); }, isEmpty: function () { return 0 === this.count(); }, current: function () { if (this.isEmpty()) { return null; } return this.nodes[this.idx]; }, reset: function () { this.nodes = []; this.idx = 0; }, count: function () { return this.nodes.length; }, }; function showCurrent(state) { var currentNode = state.current(), currentRect, searchRect; if (currentNode) { reveal(currentNode); highlight(root, currentNode, state.nodes); if ('scrollIntoView' in currentNode) { currentNode.scrollIntoView(true); currentRect = currentNode.getBoundingClientRect(); searchRect = search.getBoundingClientRect(); if (currentRect.top < (searchRect.top + searchRect.height)) { window.scrollBy(0, -(searchRect.top + searchRect.height + 5)); } } } counter.textContent = (state.isEmpty() ? 0 : state.idx + 1) + ' of ' + state.count(); } var search = doc.createElement('div'); search.className = 'sf-dump-search-wrapper sf-dump-search-hidden'; search.innerHTML = ' <input type="text" class="sf-dump-search-input"> <span class="sf-dump-search-count">0 of 0<\/span> <button type="button" class="sf-dump-search-input-previous" tabindex="-1"> <svg viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M1683 1331l-166 165q-19 19-45 19t-45-19L896 965l-531 531q-19 19-45 19t-45-19l-166-165q-19-19-19-45.5t19-45.5l742-741q19-19 45-19t45 19l742 741q19 19 19 45.5t-19 45.5z"\/><\/svg> <\/button> <button type="button" class="sf-dump-search-input-next" tabindex="-1"> <svg viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M1683 808l-742 741q-19 19-45 19t-45-19L109 808q-19-19-19-45.5t19-45.5l166-165q19-19 45-19t45 19l531 531 531-531q19-19 45-19t45 19l166 165q19 19 19 45.5t-19 45.5z"\/><\/svg> <\/button> '; root.insertBefore(search, root.firstChild); var state = new SearchState(); var searchInput = search.querySelector('.sf-dump-search-input'); var counter = search.querySelector('.sf-dump-search-count'); var searchInputTimer = 0; var previousSearchQuery = ''; addEventListener(searchInput, 'keyup', function (e) { var searchQuery = e.target.value; /* Don't perform anything if the pressed key didn't change the query */ if (searchQuery === previousSearchQuery) { return; } previousSearchQuery = searchQuery; clearTimeout(searchInputTimer); searchInputTimer = setTimeout(function () { state.reset(); collapseAll(root); resetHighlightedNodes(root); if ('' === searchQuery) { counter.textContent = '0 of 0'; return; } var classMatches = [ "sf-dump-str", "sf-dump-key", "sf-dump-public", "sf-dump-protected", "sf-dump-private", ].map(xpathHasClass).join(' or '); var xpathResult = doc.evaluate('.//span[' + classMatches + '][contains(translate(child::text(), ' + xpathString(searchQuery.toUpperCase()) + ', ' + xpathString(searchQuery.toLowerCase()) + '), ' + xpathString(searchQuery.toLowerCase()) + ')]', root, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null); while (node = xpathResult.iterateNext()) state.nodes.push(node); showCurrent(state); }, 400); }); Array.from(search.querySelectorAll('.sf-dump-search-input-next, .sf-dump-search-input-previous')).forEach(function (btn) { addEventListener(btn, 'click', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); -1 !== e.target.className.indexOf('next') ? state.next() : state.previous(); searchInput.focus(); collapseAll(root); showCurrent(state); }) }); addEventListener(root, 'keydown', function (e) { var isSearchActive = !/\bsf-dump-search-hidden\b/.test(search.className); if ((114 === e.keyCode && !isSearchActive) || (isCtrlKey(e) && 70 === e.keyCode)) { /* F3 or CMD/CTRL + F */ if (70 === e.keyCode && document.activeElement === searchInput) { /* * If CMD/CTRL + F is hit while having focus on search input, * the user probably meant to trigger browser search instead. * Let the browser execute its behavior: */ return; } e.preventDefault(); search.className = search.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-search-hidden\b/, ''); searchInput.focus(); } else if (isSearchActive) { if (27 === e.keyCode) { /* ESC key */ search.className += ' sf-dump-search-hidden'; e.preventDefault(); resetHighlightedNodes(root); searchInput.value = ''; } else if ( (isCtrlKey(e) && 71 === e.keyCode) /* CMD/CTRL + G */ || 13 === e.keyCode /* Enter */ || 114 === e.keyCode /* F3 */ ) { e.preventDefault(); e.shiftKey ? state.previous() : state.next(); collapseAll(root); showCurrent(state); } } }); } if (0 >= options.maxStringLength) { return; } try { elt = root.querySelectorAll('.sf-dump-str'); len = elt.length; i = 0; t = []; while (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); len = t.length; for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) { elt = t[i]; s = elt.innerText || elt.textContent; x = s.length - options.maxStringLength; if (0 < x) { h = elt.innerHTML; elt[elt.innerText ? 'innerText' : 'textContent'] = s.substring(0, options.maxStringLength); elt.className += ' sf-dump-str-collapse'; elt.innerHTML = '<span class=sf-dump-str-collapse>'+h+'<a class="sf-dump-ref sf-dump-str-toggle" title="Collapse"> &#9664;</a></span>'+ '<span class=sf-dump-str-expand>'+elt.innerHTML+'<a class="sf-dump-ref sf-dump-str-toggle" title="'+x+' remaining characters"> &#9654;</a></span>'; } } } catch (e) { } }; })(document); 
</script>
<style>
    pre.sf-dump {
        display: block;
        white-space: pre;
        padding: 5px;
        overflow: initial !important;
    }

    pre.sf-dump:after {
        content: "";
        visibility: hidden;
        display: block;
        height: 0;
        clear: both;
    }

    pre.sf-dump span {
        display: inline;
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-compact {
        display: none;
    }

    pre.sf-dump a {
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 0;
        outline: none;
        color: inherit;
    }

    pre.sf-dump img {
        max-width: 50em;
        max-height: 50em;
        margin: .5em 0 0 0;
        padding: 0;
        background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAAAAAA6mKC9AAAAHUlEQVQY02O8zAABilCaiQEN0EeA8QuUcX9g3QEAAjcC5piyhyEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) #D3D3D3;
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-ellipsis {
        display: inline-block;
        overflow: visible;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        max-width: 5em;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-ellipsis+.sf-dump-ellipsis {
        max-width: none;
    }

    pre.sf-dump code {
        display: inline;
        padding: 0;
        background: none;
    }

    .sf-dump-str-collapse .sf-dump-str-collapse {
        display: none;
    }

    .sf-dump-str-expand .sf-dump-str-expand {
        display: none;
    }

    .sf-dump-public.sf-dump-highlight,
    .sf-dump-protected.sf-dump-highlight,
    .sf-dump-private.sf-dump-highlight,
    .sf-dump-str.sf-dump-highlight,
    .sf-dump-key.sf-dump-highlight {
        background: rgba(111, 172, 204, 0.3);
        border: 1px solid #7DA0B1;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }

    .sf-dump-public.sf-dump-highlight-active,
    .sf-dump-protected.sf-dump-highlight-active,
    .sf-dump-private.sf-dump-highlight-active,
    .sf-dump-str.sf-dump-highlight-active,
    .sf-dump-key.sf-dump-highlight-active {
        background: rgba(253, 175, 0, 0.4);
        border: 1px solid #ffa500;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-hidden {
        display: none !important;
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper {
        font-size: 0;
        white-space: nowrap;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        display: flex;
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        position: sticky;
        top: 5px;
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper>* {
        vertical-align: top;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 21px;
        font-weight: normal;
        border-radius: 0;
        background: #FFF;
        color: #757575;
        border: 1px solid #BBB;
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper>input.sf-dump-search-input {
        padding: 3px;
        height: 21px;
        font-size: 12px;
        border-right: none;
        border-top-left-radius: 3px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
        color: #000;
        min-width: 15px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper>.sf-dump-search-input-next,
    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper>.sf-dump-search-input-previous {
        background: #F2F2F2;
        outline: none;
        border-left: none;
        font-size: 0;
        line-height: 0;
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper>.sf-dump-search-input-next {
        border-top-right-radius: 3px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper>.sf-dump-search-input-next>svg,
    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper>.sf-dump-search-input-previous>svg {
        pointer-events: none;
        width: 12px;
        height: 12px;
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper>.sf-dump-search-count {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0 5px;
        margin: 0;
        border-left: none;
        line-height: 21px;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    pre.sf-dump,
    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-default {
        background-color: #18171B;
        color: #FF8400;
        line-height: 1.2em;
        font: 12px Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, monospace;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        white-space: pre-wrap;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 99999;
        word-break: break-all
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-num {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #1299DA
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-const {
        font-weight: bold
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-str {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #56DB3A
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-note {
        color: #1299DA
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-ref {
        color: #A0A0A0
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-public {
        color: #FFFFFF
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-protected {
        color: #FFFFFF
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-private {
        color: #FFFFFF
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-meta {
        color: #B729D9
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-key {
        color: #56DB3A
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-index {
        color: #1299DA
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-ellipsis {
        color: #FF8400
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-ns {
        user-select: none;
    }

    pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-ellipsis-note {
        color: #1299DA
    }
</style>
<pre class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-256116292 data-indent-pad="  ">[]
</pre>
<script>
    Sfdump("sf-dump-256116292")
</script>
```

My api.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Modules\UserManagement\Entities\UserGroup;
use Modules\UserManagement\Entities\UserAccount;
use Modules\UserManagement\Entities\Session;

use Modules\UserManagement\Transformers\UserGroupResource;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::prefix('usermanagement')->group(function () {

    Route::prefix('useraccounts')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', 'UserAccountsController@getUserAccounts');

        Route::get('/{userid}', 'UserAccountsController@getUserByUserId');

        //Route::post('/', 'UserAccountsController@postUser');
        Route::post('/', function (Request $request) {
           var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")));
           var_dump($request->all());
           var_dump($_REQUEST);
           dd($request->json()->all());
           dd($request->all());
        });
    });
});
```

I hope you have any ideas what I could have misconfigured, or where I should start looking.
Thank you for your help and advice in advance.

Cheers,

Franz

Comment: can you use dd(request()->all()); to see the results?

Comment: Are you sure that the data coming from file_get_contents("php://input") is json ? If so, why are you making it php array by json_decode rather than returning it as it is ?
If you are sure that you are getting json from file_get_contents("php://input")), try 
return file_get_contents("php://input")); and  check the result.

Comment: Update your question and put `dd($request->json()->all())` output.

Comment: Updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `json_decode` on the `$request` object?

The object you receive is not just a raw response string, it's an object that has [a number of methods](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#retrieving-input) that can be used to retrieve the data from the request.

In your case for example you can use `$request->all()` to get all values that have been received by the request. Keep in mind however that this will also return query parameters if there are any. So it is recommended to use `$request->input('user_name')` to retrieve each value separately.

Comment: Sorry, I have never used dependency Injection on a Request as I am relatively new to lavarel. But thanks for your advice. Btw. updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
I made another Laravel Project and tried it there.
Initially it didn't work either, but then I switched back to the original project, played a little bit around with composer and somehow it suddenly worked.
I don't know which exact command resolved this issue, but one thing I remember, is that I ran "composer i".